# Adding someones input from JOptionPane into an Array

Tags: java, arraylist

Hey everyone Someone might have asked this but Im trying to implement an ArrayList from a users answer I have done some research and it wont do. Here's my code < part of it

```
public class Breed
{

public static void cross_breed()
    {
        // Creates 3 strings named male_breed, female_breed, and cross_breed. 
        String male_breed;   
        String female_breed;
        String cross_breed;
        Cross_breed crossbreed;
        List<String> clist = new ArrayList<String>();

        while (true)  // While the male_breed is a real breed continue on with the program
        {
            male_breed = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("What is the breed of the male?");
            if (male_breed.length() == 0) break; // Makes it so if the male dog breed wasn't entered the program will exit
            if (List_Breeds.blist.containsKey(male_breed))  //If the given input of the users is on the list of breeds continue with program
            {
                while (true) // Loops the female breed
                {
                    female_breed = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("What is the breed of the Female");
                    if (List_Breeds.blist.containsKey(female_breed)) //
                    {
                        if (male_breed.equals(female_breed)) // if both breeds are the same
                        {
                            clist.add(JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,  "Your dog is a Purebread " + male_breed));
                            break; //Ends the program
                        } 
                        else  
                        {

                            cross_breed = male_breed.substring(0, 3) + "a" + female_breed.substring(0, 3);     //If both breeds arent the same take the           
                            clist.add(JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Your dog breed is a " + cross_breed));         // first three letters of the male_breed and inserts
                            break;  // Ends the program                                                                     // an 'A' at the end.
                        }
```

Eclipse is giving me an error saying for both lines

```
clist.add(JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,  "Your dog is a Purebread " + male_breed));
```

and

```
clist.add(JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Your dog breed is a " + cross_breed));
```

that states "the method add in the Type List is not applicable for the arguments (void)

if I'm doing this wrong please help... What I am trying to do is add the breed (or cross breed) name to an arraylist in which will be displayed in a second menu

Answer (score 0):

"the method add in the Type List is not applicable for the arguments (void)" mean the method you're calling - `JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(JComponent, String)` does not return anything.

This is because showMessageDialog is for showing messages, not capturing input.

You need to take a look at the various flavours of `JOptionPane.showInputDialog()` in order to get input from the user.